# do I have the private messaging function set up correctly on my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed the simple private messaging plugin (https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages) but I've been having some issues trying to get this working using user.name (NOT user.login). I'm not getting any error messages but it seems that none of the sent messages are getting received and nothing is getting displayed under "sent".

First here's the schema of users

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
```

schema for message

```
create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.boolean  "sender_deleted",    :default => false
    t.boolean  "recipient_deleted", :default => false
    t.string   "subject"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "read_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                           :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           :null => false
  end
```

Message controller
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController

```
  before_filter :set_user

def index
if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
  @messages = @user.sent_messages
else
  @messages = @user.received_messages
end
end

def show
@message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end

def new
@message = Message.new

if params[:reply_to]
  @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
  unless @reply_to.nil?
    @message.to = @reply_to.sender.name
    @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
    @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
  end
end
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find_by_name(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
end

def delete_selected
if request.post?
  if params[:delete]
    params[:delete].each { |id|
      @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
      @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
    }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
end

private
def set_user
 @user = User.first
end
end
```

Message model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :to, :subject, :body
  is_private_message

  attr_accessor :to

end
```

Messages index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag delete_selected_user_messages_path(@user, :method => :post) do %>
    <% if params[:mailbox] == "sent" %>
            <%= render :partial => "sent" %>
    <% else %>
            <%= render :partial => "inbox" %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Messages sent.html.erb

```
<h2>Sent</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Del?</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Sent</th>
    </tr>
    <% if @messages.size == 0 %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                No messages
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% else %>
        <% for message in @messages %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "delete[]", message.id %></td>
                <td><%= link_to h(message.subject), user_message_path(@user, message) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to h(message.recipient.login), user_path(message.recipient) %></td>
              <td><%=h message.created_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <%= submit_tag "Delete" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
<%= link_to "Inbox", user_messages_path(@user)%>
```

Did I do something  incorrect? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From your terminal, type rails console to launch the console and type Message.all. This will return all the records inside the Messages table. See if there are any ids that are missing. See if the messages are tagging to the right users.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful to look at. I noticed that all of the recipient_id: nil. Do you know how the "To" box should be addressed? I was trying to use the 'name"

Comment: If you look at the table, you would see that it is set to an integer. Which is expecting the id. Try inserting the Id. It should work fine :)

Comment: Do you know why when I browse to http://localhost:3000/users/8/messages, the "Sent" and "Compose" links at the bottom refer to user 1? For example, the link shows as this http://localhost:3000/users/1/messages?mailbox=sent even when viewing as user 8

Comment: Hold on let me just check the documentation. It's probably some security feature that only shows the user's own messages. That would make sense no?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the controller/show

```
def show
  @message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end
```

You see that the second parameter is always the current user. So it is returning the interaction of the current user.

Comment: I am trying to change this in my Messages controller at the very bottom- "def set_user
 @user = User.first
end".... but when I do that, I am no longer able to use code such as "message.sender.name". The "name" becomes undefined. Do you know how I can set "@user" to the current user in this case?

Comment: I mean, I tried setting to @user = current_user which fixes the links... but I get undefined in "name" when I click on them

Comment: actually, I fixed those by using current_user. However, one last remaining issue is this. When I click "Sent", I get "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}". Any idea on this last one?

Comment: That's great! I'm pretty sure it should point to controller=>"messages" no? In another terminal window, you could use the command, "rake routes" to see the list of available routes and to which contorller/action they point to. Check your route is pointing to the right one :D

Comment: I'm looking into this now. One last thing I was wondering, do you know how I can limit users from going into other user's message links? For example, user "3" can press "http://localhost:3000/users/8/messages/new" and be able to send messages as user 8

Comment: You could do a precheck like "if current_user == params[:id]" and throw an error if they don't match :)